# View HTML5 Video on iOS devices without going to full screen

Tags: css, html, video

Mobile Safari on the iPhone does not allow videos to play inline, they must always go fullscreen. Is there any way to play html5 video inline?

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting. Why would apple imply limitations to development?
Came across this:

Source: http://blog.millermedeiros.com/unsolved-html5-video-issues-on-ios/

**No way to play video inline on the iPhone**

Videos always plays full-screen on the iPhone (as of iOS 4.2), I’m “sure” that it isn’t a technical issue since iAds can play inline videos without any problems and the iAd is simply an embedded UIWebView. – it seems that Apple doesn’t want webapps to succeed since they don’t pay 30% of the sales to them – And don’t say that it is because the user won’t have enough available screen area to watch the video, that it is for a “better experience”, that it “saves battery”.. it is all nonsense, the browser UI don’t need to be so obstructive and in some specific cases it is totally fine to have the video playing on a small area, they are “doing it on purpose” just to push users to the app-based browsing (which they control and profit with).